# Position sticky not working in IE or Safari

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am creating a card in CSS. It works perfectly fine in Chrome but doesn't work in IE/Safari browser.

```css
#nb {
    position: sticky;
    width: 280px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#nb:hover:after {
    background: #f79031!important;
}
#nb::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 940%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 170px;
    right: -502%;
    background: #ffffff;
    transform-origin: 54% 0;
    transform: rotate(129deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

#nb h5{text-align: left;
line-height: 25px;
padding-left: 7%;}
```

```html
<div id="nb">
 <a href="http://www.wissentechnology.com/banking-financial/"><img
  class="bimg"
  src="https://wissen-kenvent.rhcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Banking-Financial.jpg"
  style="width: 100%;" />
  <h5 style="font-size: x-large; color: #000000; padding-top: 15px;">Banking
   & Finance</h5>
  <h4
   style="color: #000000; padding-top: 15px; text-align: justify; padding-left: 7%; padding-right: 7%;">We
   bring the right mix of domain and technical expertise to help you
   take emerging imperatives head on and translate them to competitive
   advantage.</h4> </a>
</div>
```

Created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7uszgry/)

Comment: `position: sticky` is not supported by IE --> http://caniuse.com/css-sticky/embed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the position of #nb to relative fixes the issue.

```
#nb {
    position: relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Webkit is the HTML/CSS rendering engine used in Apple's Safari browser.

Use `-webkit-sticky` instead of `sticky` for Safari.

```
#nb {
     position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```